# Error while trying to delete a variable in a dataframe in Python 3.6.3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, compiler-errors

I have a database with 322,098 observations and 3,868 variables. To test the script I generated a sub-sample with 50 observations and 3,868 variables. When I run the script in the sub-sample it works perfectly. However, when I try to run with the complete database (322,098 remarks) deleting the trade variable from the dataframe gives error.

The following is the script:

```
## Load External DataSet

mydata = pd.read_csv ('C:\\Users\\Inspiron\\Desktop\\policies.csv', sep = ',', na_values = '.')

## Normalized Data

mydata ['normalized'] = (mydata ['trade'] - mydata ['trade'].min ())/(mydata ['trade'].max () - mydata ['trade'].min ())

## Descriptive Statistics for a Single Variable

mydata ['normalized'].describe ()

## Drop Columns

mydata = mydata.drop (['trade'], axis = 1)
```

The following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Inspiron\OneDrive\academic\articles\2018\non-discriminatory\script-dofile\mfn.py", line 31, in <module>
mydata = mydata.drop (['trade'], axis = 1)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2530, in drop
obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2563, in _drop_axis
dropped = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 127, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2935, in reindex
return super(DataFrame, self).reindex(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3004, in reindex
self._consolidate_inplace()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3677, in _consolidate_inplace
self._protect_consolidate(f)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3666, in _protect_consolidate
result = f()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3675, in f
self._data = self._data.consolidate()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3826, in consolidate
bm._consolidate_inplace()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3831, in _consolidate_inplace
self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4853, in _consolidate
_can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4876, in _merge_blocks
new_values = new_values[argsort]
MemoryError
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler` instead:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

mms = MinMaxScaler()

# use `.to_frame()` to prevent `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:`    
mydata['normalized'] = mms.fit_transform(mydata.pop('trade').to_frame())
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the normalized variable from the trade variable normalize the trade variable directly.

Follow the command:

```
## Normalized Data

mydata ['trade'] = (mydata ['trade'] - mydata ['trade'].min ())/(mydata ['trade'].max () - mydata ['trade'].min ())
```